# Connecting on Shell with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, shell, command-line, phpmyadmin

This is a very stupid question but I don't catch where is the problem.

I try to connect through Shell to my MySQL database using the command. I can connect, but I don't see any of the databases I created using phpMyAdmin, even if I'm using the root user (who has all the privileges).
[image: Databases of my MySQL server through Shell]

And here the databases on my phpMyAdmin :

[image: Databases of my MySQL server through phpMyAdmin]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: with which account you logged into phpmyadmin and seeing the databases? root user?

Comment: Yes ! It's mentionned on the homepage of phpMyAdmin ( root@localhost )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is more than one MySQL instance running on different ports.